# Interfaces as map keys

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

In the following code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Object interface {
  String() string
}

type Person struct {
  Name string
}

func (p *Person) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("person: %s", p.Name)
}

func main() {
  dict := map[Object]int{
    &Person{Name: "xyz"}: 4,
    &Person{Name: "gle"}: 2,
    &Person{Name: "kp3"}: 7,
  }

  fmt.Println(dict[&Person{Name: "xyz"}])
}
```

It just prints `0`, because the map's keys are `Objects`, which are interfaces. I know why this happens, but is there any way to get around it? I want to be able to have a map whose keys are interface types, but which I can still access fields of.

The only way I've thought of so far would be to iterate through each key and check if the key is equal to the thing I'm searching for, but it would likely be *significantly* slower.

Comment: This looks like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you actually trying to accomplish? Map keys should *usually* just be keys, if you need behavior from them to where you want an interface type, you might want to consider a different approach.

Comment: The reason my keys are interface types is because I'm making a language in which a program can make a map, where both keys _and_ values are the same type: an Object.

Comment: That doesn't  mean that the interpreter should use Go `map`s to implement that language's maps.

Comment: True, but it seems like it'd be a lot of effort to implement my own map type.

Comment: Writing a language interpreter [requires a lot of effort](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work if you define your method on a struct rather than a pointer: https://play.golang.org/p/zU4sbFe2RB.

If you can't do that in real code, I'm afraid you can't accomplish what you want. These two pointers will be different values, even if they point to similar data.

You can add an `Equals(Object) bool` method to the `Object` interface and roll out your own implementation of a map. Alternatively, you can define `Hash() string` method and use a `map[string]whatever`.

Comment: I'll probably just implement my own map.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it may be a misuse of maps; if you're keying the map off of the `String()` value of the objects (the only thing the objects have in common), you might try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Object interface {
    String() string
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("person: %s", p.Name)
}

func main() {
    xyz := &Person{Name: "xyz"}
    gle := &Person{Name: "gle"}
    kp3 := &Person{Name: "kp3"}
    dict := map[string]int{
        xyz.String(): 4,
        gle.String(): 2,
        kp3.String(): 7,
    }

    fmt.Println(dict[xyz.String()])
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I'd have to change a lot of my code for it to work.